# The meaning of word earned

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The meaning of word earned in this sentence: "Ashton lifted Gillian up and earned her to the kitchen"

Comment: What's the source of this sentence?

Comment: She probably has a poor OCR reader.

Answer (score 3):

There is no “earned” in that sentence:

> [image: screenshot of a scanned copy of the book paragraph]

It’s very clearly “carried”.